# Redirection fails : react-native-svg : React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: react-native, svg, expo, react-native-svg

I'm trying to understand an error. When I redirect my first screen on another one I get on the bundler :

> "Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
> (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
> components) but got: %s.%s%s, object,"

I guess the problem is with the package svg - It's when I click on :

```
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Distance")}>
        <View style={styles.statContainer}>
          <ImageBackground
            source={require("../../assets/images/stats-background-1.png")}
            style={styles.statImage}
          >
            <View style={styles.row}>
              <Text style={styles.statText}>
                {i18n.t("stats.action.dist")}
                {"\n"}
                <AnimateNumber
                  value={this.state.stats.total_distance}
                  countBy={(this.state.stats.total_distance / 50).toFixed(0)}
                  style={styles.statTextData}
                />{" "}
                {i18n.t("stats.unit.kilometre")}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

[image]

The code of the second screen is :

```
export default class Stats extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    };

  render() {
    return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.containerScrollNoMargins}>
      <Header
        backgroundImage={require("../../assets/images/bg-header.png")}
        centerComponent={{
          text: i18n.t("stats.title"),
          style: styles.headerComponentStyle,
        }}
        containerStyle={styles.headerContainerStyle}
        statusBarProps={{ barStyle: "light-content" }}
      />
      <ImageBackground
        source={require("../../assets/images/background-stats.jpg")}
        style={{flex : 1 }}
        imageStyle={{ resizeMode: 'stretch' }}
      >
         <Svg height="50%" width="50%">
             <Image href={require('../../assets/images/Interface_Stat_1.svg')} />
        </Svg>
      </ImageBackground>
    </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

I don't get what is the error, can you please give me any tips, any help ?
Thanks a lot for your time and explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to fail cause you use the `Image` component of RN inside the `SVG` tag.

It only supports for children in [list](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#supported-elements), and `Image` only supports those some formats like `png, jpg, jpeg, bmp, gif, webp, psd` as mentioned [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source). To fix this, you can take a look at [react-native-svg-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer), it will help you easily importing local svg file.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have another error but thanks to you I understand better the way it works, thanks.

Comment: For me the  react-native-svg-transformer fixed the issue